# How can I access IME preferences loaded from XML in keyboard service on android?

Tags: android, keyboard, ime, android-input-method, android-settings

I am trying to create my own custom software keyboard for Android.I inspired myself [by this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615), so my keyboard service *onCreateInputView()* looks like:

```
...
private KeyboardView keyboardView;
private Keyboard defaultKeyboard;
private Keyboard charKeyboard;
...
@Override
public View onCreateInputView()
{
    defaultKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.alphabet_letter_keyboard);
    charKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.specialcharacter_keyboard);
    keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboardView.setKeyboard(defaultKeyboard);
...
```

I also looked at the way AOSP-Keyboard is implementing the keyboard preferences  (In the Android settings -> input method, if you click on the Keyboard Name you reach the keyboards settings screen), so I settings from XML-file like:

```
public static class Settings extends InputMethodSettingsFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setInputMethodSettingsCategoryTitle(R.string.layout_selection_title);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.ime_preferences);
...
```

The XML settings look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/select_layout">
        android:title="Layouts"
        android:key="layouts"
        android:summary="Click to select the keyboard layout"
        android:defaultValue="qwertz"
        android:entries="@array/list"
        android:entryValues="@array/values"
        ></ListPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

so I can choose in the settings from different layouts (qwerty, alphabetic ...). What I would like to achieve is to access the selected value in the keyboardService *onCreateInputView()* method, so the right layout will be taken for the *defaultKeyboard* instance.

E.g.

```
@Override
public View onCreateInputView()
{        
    // Access the list setting value of the selected layout
    String selectedLayout = ...
    switch(selectedLayout) { // Initialize keyboard with abcde or qwert layout
        case "abcde":
            defaultKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.alphabet_letter_keyboard);
            break;
        case "qwert":
            defaultKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.typewriter_letter_keyboard);
            break;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. You can access the settings with

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.getString("layouts", "qwert")
```

The second parameter by *prefs.getString* is the default value. For changing the keyboard layout on setting-change you need to implement *onSharedPreferenceChanged* method

The general code looks than like this:

```
public class KeyboardService extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
private KeyboardView keyboardView;
private Keyboard defaultKeyboard;
private Keyboard charKeyboard;
private boolean isCaps = true; //Start the keyboard in Caps-layout
private boolean isCharKeyboard = false; //Start the keyboard with letter-layout
SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
public View onCreateInputView()
{
    // SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("ime_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // register preference change listener
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    // Set the initial layout according to the initial layout selection
    switch(prefs.getString("layouts", "qwert")) { // Initialize keyboard with abcde or qwert layout
        case "abcde":
            defaultKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.alphabet_letter_keyboard);
            break;
        case "qwert":
            defaultKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.typewriter_letter_keyboard);
            break;
    }

...

// handle updates to preferences
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    if (key.equals("layouts")) {
        switch(prefs.getString("layouts", "qwert")) { // Initialize keyboard with abcde or qwert layout
        case "abcde":
            defaultKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.alphabet_letter_keyboard);
            break;
        case "qwert":
            defaultKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.typewriter_letter_keyboard);
            break;
    }
    keyboardView.setKeyboard(defaultKeyboard);
    setInputView(this.onCreateInputView());
    }
}
```